# Can someone make sure that my understanding of D-caches is accurate?

Tags: caching, architecture

I'm working on a problem (I'm going to change the problem here a bit because I'm more interested in someone checking my knowledge) that goes something along the lines of:

You have three 10x20 two-dimensional arrays A, B, and C. They all hold double precision floating point numbers. There's a D-cache that's 2048 lines long, each of which is 256 bytes long. It's in row-major order.

You then have some code that runs like:

```
for(i = 0 to 9)
    for(j = 0 to 19)
      C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j]
```

A is at address 0x10014000, B is at address 0x10019000 and C is at address 0x1001E000

And the question asks for the read hits and write misses.

now, as far as I understand, double precision floating point numbers are 8 bytes long. Since the line lengths are 256 bytes each, each line of the cache can hold 32 values, correct? And since it's 2048 lines long, the cache can hold 65536 values. Right?

A, B, and C each have 200 elements in them. Does that mean that everything after the first read-ins of A and B all of the readings from the array would be read hits? And there would only be one write miss-- when C isn't first loaded into the D-cache?

Is that accurate, or am I mistaken? That doesn't sound right but I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. The first "filling" of A and b only fill one cache line, in your example, which is from 0x10014000 to 0x100140ff for matrix A. And when 0x10014100 is needed, cache miss will occur in matrix A again.

What's more

> now, as far as I understand, double precision floating point numbers are 8 bytes long. Since the line lengths are 256 bytes each, each line of the cache can hold 32 values, correct? And since it's 2048 lines long, the cache can hold 65536 values. Right?

It is right. But It cannot be concluded that there will be no cache miss if cache capacity is larger that the content, unless the cache is fully associative. That is called "Collision". There are some links about cache associativity:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Associativity
- http://csillustrated.berkeley.edu/PDFs/handouts/cache-3-associativity-handout.pdf